# Program exit when return in a function

Tags: bash, exit, exit-status

This is a extract of my code:

```
ninja ()
{
  if $1 = toto
  then
  return 1
  elif $1 = tata
  then
  return 4
  fi
}

main () {
  ninja "tata"
  if [ $? -ne 1 ]
  then
    somecode
  fi
}

main "$@"
```

For no reason, when my function return something, the program just exit (I've tested with a trap EXIT), the function return 4 and execute the trap.

Edit : works when I comment

```
set -o errexit
set -o errtrace
```

But how Can I found the error ?

Comment: Do you have `set -e` in your script?

Comment: There was not conflict, I've found that redefinition allowed and for calling builtin command then you need a `builtin <command>` construct.

Comment: Please mark answer if it solves your problem or comment you troubles.  Thank you.

Comment: @StephenKitt It works when I comment  
    set -o errexit
    set -o errtrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test that function argument equivalent to some string, you must use construct `if [ "$x" == "string" ]`, then your code will looks like:

```
test () {
  if [ "$1" == "toto" ] then
    return 1
  elif [ "$1" == "tata" ] then
    return 4
  fi
}

main () {
  test "tata"
  if [ $? -ne 1 ] then
    echo "somecode"
  fi
}

main "$@"
```

And you could use `test` name for the function.  If you want to call builtin `test`, then use `builtin test` construct.

And take care about `=` (assignment) and `==` (comparison).  Inside the test `[` and `]` the `=` operator works like `==` and tests the string equality (not numbers).

`set -o errexit` exits immediately after command returns non-zero (non-succesful).  Your `ninja` returns `1` (which is non-zero) and exit.

Your code without tests is not working cause `if` statement tries to execute instructions into it and determine the exit state of the command: if the exit state is zero (success), then execute instructions after `then` till `elif` of `fi`.

Comment: It's not this. I check another thing but it's for the exemple of the structure of my code. I put test in name of function but it's not his true name.

Why `=` works in this case ? `if [ toto = 5 ]` ?

Comment: Inside the test [ and ] the = operator works like == and tests the string equality (not numbers).

Comment: OKKKKKK Thanks a lot, i didn't knew that ! It's always a pleasure to learn from Stack ! :)